# How to get image support in xterm-terminal?

Tags: command-line, xterm

I want to know how to view images (.jpg, .png) via terminal (xterm or gnome).

Please help me. How to enable visual support inside terminal?

Answer (score 3):

Use the command [feh](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/feh.1.html).

```
feh {/path/to/image.png}
```

> feh is a mode-based image viewer.  It is especially aimed at command line users who need a fast image viewer without huge GUI dependencies, though it can also be started by
>   (graphical) file managers to view an image.  By default (unless arguments or a filelist are specified), feh displays all files in the current directory.
>
> feh can open any format supported by Imlib2, most notably jpeg, png, pnm, tiff, and bmp. The gif format is also supported, but only for static images. In case of animations, only the first frame will be shown.

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu the standard image viewer is **EyeOfGnome** - eog. From terminal simply type:

```
eog name_of_picture.jpg
```